# WordNetLemmatizer Function

Tags: python, nltk

Beginner's question, I have a text file of 250 sentences, and I've already tokenized them, and put the tokens in a list, like this

[image: the list of tokens]

Now I want to lemmatize each word using the WordNetLemmatizer

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
lemmatizer.lemmatize(tokens)

but this happens,

[image]

please tell me what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This will work probably.

```
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
results = []
for token in tokens:
    result = lemmatizer.lemmatize(token)
    results.append(result)
print(results)
```

Comment: How about `results = lemmatizer.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens`?

Comment: Ya works. And the precise way. `results = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens]` though.

Comment: Yeah silly me, I'm just having my first coffee of the day... :)